# Как сделать аутентификация с помощью email в Parse?

Tags: java, android, parse.com

Стандартная аутентификация в Parse проходит с помощью UserName, но 
Приложение должно получать от usera только его меил и пароль. Нашел способ заносить емаил в столбец Username, но тогда user может ввести не корректный мейл и он запишется в Parse, из за этого возникнут сложности с отправкой забытого пароля и т.д.
Как сделать аутентификация с помощью мейла и как проверять мейл на корректность.